# Understanding JavaScript Shorthand (if / &&)

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I'm trying to understand this line of code somebody else wrote:

```
myVar1 = myVar1 && myJsonData.myObj[filterName]['myKey'][0] === myFilterValue;
```

Can somebody please tell what this means (without shortening)!? Thanks

Comment: You're right. Didn't realize where I was typing. Removing my comment since there is a better answer below.

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `myVar1` is a "falsy" value<sup>*</sup>, then it remains with its current value. (The `&&` operator will not evaluate its right operand if the left operand evaluates to `false`.) Otherwise, `myVar1` will be set to either `true` or `false`, according to the value of the comparison

```
myJsonData.myObj[filterName]['myKey'][0] === myFilterValue
```

* <sub>"falsy" values in JavaScript are `false`, 0, `""` (the empty string), `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`.</sub>